Travelling abroad (Schengen) while waiting for new residency card
TLDR; My wife and I would like to travel to the Canary Islands (Spain) while she is waiting for her renewed Temporary Residency Card (TRC).
I am Polish. My wife is Georgian. We are thinking about going with my kids (Polish) to the Canary Islands for winter holidays. However, her TRC expires in January 2025 and the winter holidays in Poland start in February.
We got married June 2024 and we already got our Georgian marriage certificate transcribed into the Polish system with Polish version of it (we also have scanned version of original Georgian marriage certificate with English translation included in it).
She has been working, studying and living here in Poland for the last 3 years - unfortunately this is not enough for permanent residency card here (and marriage-based is not issued until 3 years after marriage).
My kids and I can travel using our Polish ID cards. She is using TRC (with previous surname) or her Georgian passport (with current surname, changed after marriage - although she joined both her and mine surname)
She applied for a new TRC in July, attached Polish marriage certificate but the waiting time here for a new card is pretty long - up to 6-10 months (even though by law it is 60 days, in practice it is almost always postponed because of a lot of people applying).
Also, as a technicality, she applied for the temporary residence extension (now based on marriage, previous was based on work, she also made Polish diploma in meantime) and after a positive decision she needs an appointment to get the actual card (2-4 weeks after positive decision for temporary residency extension).
Now according to what we read:

when waiting for TRC a person cannot leave the country (= technically can, but to reenter one needs a visa again)
the above seems to not take into account that we are married and I am a EU citizen (which seems to grant my wife the right to travel with me ... but details here are not clear for me)
inside Schengen (both Poland and Spain and we plan to travel by plane) generally there are no obligatory border checks (with exception introduced recently by Germany)
she is worried that travelling may accidentally "cancel" her TRC application on which her current job is based (and generally the possibility to work in Poland legally)

We are planning a short trip (7 days) and to have everything booked in advance (hotel, return plane tickets) to fly from Warsaw Chopin (WAW) to one of the Tenerife airports (TNS, TNF).

How likely is it that she will be fine on her trip?

How risky is the trip? (e.g. suddenly Poland introducing border control for Schengen area, same as Germany, could make my wife unable to travel back?)

How can we minimize the risk of any inconveniences?


Similar questions:
Traveling within Schengen while waiting for EEA residence card?
When does a Schengen residence card validity terminate?
Reference materials I found and read:
Polish rules for TRC and work permit:
https://migrant.poznan.uw.gov.pl/en/procedury/temporary-residence-and-work-permit
https://www.gov.pl/web/udsc-en/eu-citizen--family-member-of-an-eu-citizen - FAQ about EU citizen family members including this part

I am married to an EU citizen who lives in Poland, do I need a visa to enter Poland?


You can enter the territory of Poland based on a valid travel document and a visa, as long as you come from a country for which a visa is required. You can also enter Poland on the basis of a document issued by another Member State corresponding to the residence card of a family member of an EU citizen or a permanent residence card of a family member of an EU citizen, or on the basis of a valid Polish residence card.


Quick remarks: You being an EU citizen does not grant her the right to easy re-entry without a visa as she's a visa national. In theory the consulate should be able to issue her a visa in less than 14 days, but that's after the appointment, and you know how long the wait line for appointments can be. Also about temporary border controls, this is not a Germany thing. Many countries have temporary border controls established on certain borders, often but not always land: https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/schengen-area/temporary-reintroduction-border-control_en

It’s not clear to me if you are planning this trip, or if it is already booked. If the former, personally I would save yourself the worry and wait until the TRC is issued.

In general, EU free movement rights do not apply to third-country family members of an EU citizen with respect to the EU citizen's country of nationality.  In other words, because you are Polish, EU free movement law probably does not apply to your wife in Poland.
There are some exceptions that apply, but these typically involve the couple having lived elsewhere in the EU before going to the country of nationality.  It sounds as though your wife moved to Poland on her own and met you there, and the two of you haven't lived elsewhere in the EU, so this exception wouldn't apply.  Another exception is that certain countries have explicitly extended similar rights to the family of their citizens, but I believe that Poland is not one of these countries.  Therefore, free movement law is only relevant to your wife in Spain (and in the rest of the EU and the Schengen area aside from Poland).
Because your wife's status under Polish immigration law is governed solely by national law, your wife is right to worry that her departure from Poland could cause trouble for her pending application.  Many countries take the position that departure from the country's territory automatically cancels any such application.  I do not know whether Poland is one of these countries.
There is probably a case to be made that EU free movement law should require Poland to allow the two of you to travel together within the EU without her application being cancelled, but you probably don't want to be in the position of having to make that case.  I would try to ask the authorities whether she can make the trip without abandoning the application.
The other thing to worry about is the possibility of internal border controls.  Anywhere in the Schengen area other than Poland, your wife will be fine as long as she's with you and you can prove that you're married.  The visa called for by the free movement directive is required to enter a country, not to remain in it, and the directive requires authorities to provide an opportunity for anyone lacking a visa to prove by other means that they enjoy the right of free movement.  In your wife's case, that's three facts:

she's married to you
you are an EU citizen
she's traveling with you (or to join you).

The greater potential problem, therefore, is an internal check on return to Poland.  Once again, the best way to dispose of this worry is probably to ask the authorities.
It might also be a good idea to establish the consequences of the worst-case scenario: if she's checked on return to Poland, what would happen?  Do they cancel the application, deport her to Georgia, and make her apply for a visa?  Or do they let her in but make her submit a fresh application?  Or do they just let her in as if she'd never left?  I'm not sure it would be possible to answer this question, but you should try.
Finally, a word about the airline: some airlines, or at least Ryanair, seem to require third-country nationals not only to present a passport but also to provide evidence that they are legally present in the Schengen area.  You should check on this for your airline, or, if you haven't yet booked the tickets, for the airlines you're considering using.  Even if the Polish authorities say you can make the trip without any special considerations, it's possible that the airline might give you trouble over its documentary requirements.

@jcaron I get that some people obsess about sorting questions between the two websites but the overlap in contributors is almost total and it's very unlikely we would suddenly find someone familiar with the details of Polish law lurking there. The only real difference is where phoog's (always excellent) answers end up.

@Relaxed I wondered about that but I don't spend much time over there so I hoped there were some people lurking over there who do not routinely come over here. It's quite possible it's not the case, and if so there's indeed no reason to ask there (though I would probably not transfer the question but rather ask a question focusing on the national aspects).
